# when i open the eclipse, there is a exception: Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty

Tags: java, eclipse

After I reinstall ubuntu, i download the eclipse from eclipce site, but when I first open the eclipse , it occur a exception. I can not find the right answer by google, so i come here for help.\

Comment: Did you try reopening or restarting the computer? Mine bugged out first time also, then worked.

Comment: Could you do a screenshot?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the .metadata directory of the workspace to see if there is a more detailed message